# Rethinkdb invalid url error

Tags: rethinkdb

I have RethinkDB installed on my server and I am able to access the admin dashboard without issues, however, I am not able to connect an app to the server. I have the following code on my app:

```
r = require('rethinkdb');
r.connect({ host: 'my_server_ip_address', port: 28015 }, function(err, conn) {
  if(err) throw err;
  r.db('test').tableCreate('tv_shows').run(conn, function(err, res) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log(res);
    r.table('tv_shows').insert({ name: 'Star Trek TNG' }).run(conn, function(err, res)
    {
      if(err) throw err;
      console.log(res);
    });
  });
});
```

I have made sure to have the host address match the client address, and it is the same address I used to successfully connect to the rethinkdb admin dashboard, but for some reason, I get the following error "Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL" I don't know if I am supposed to type in a url or the ip address or what as EVERY tutorial that I have found assumes that rethinkdb is installed on a localhost, so just localhost is used as a host, which doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Probably IP address of server 109.1.0.168:port being the database port. If it helps you can Google gettingnifty heavy evil I have a MySQL connection in the main window application. Start there and look for something similar in your database. They vary by version so check Oracle etc. Or 10.0.0.1 windows is netstat -arng ( all, numerical, routing, groups), Unix is ifconfig or ipconfig I believe. If it's localhost, localhost should be subnet. In gaming applications on the client side there are advantages to opening your Nat.

Please edit